# Can I use Stage 3.x.x with ROS Hydro?

Tags: ros, roshydro, simulator-stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most of the tutorials I found is for stage version 3.x.x.. But Since Fuerte stage version is 4.x.x.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and on this version ROS Electric can not be installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193054/can-i-use-stage-3.x.x-with-ros-hydro-??/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2014-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately the Stage package is poorly documented. But I've used Stage 4.x.x with Hydro before. I recall there were some minor changes I had to make to my .world files (adding a new dimension to some variables) to make them work with the new version. But other than that everything seemed to work fine.

---

Originally posted by [nfattahi](https://answers.ros.org/users/20170/nfattahi/) with karma: 26 on 2014-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on 2014-09-19**:
I want to simulate Neato robot (LIDAR Sensor) or roomba with laser sensor but Stage 4.x.x has replaced laser with ranger and I am not very good in stage version difference and make edition in code. But I try

**Comment by [nfattahi](https://answers.ros.org/users/20170/nfattahi/) on 2014-09-19**:
You're correct. Modifying the config files should be fairly straight forward as I recall. There's always help on ROS Answers if you run into issues!